# Divide my data frame into n intervals based on datetime

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe with oldest date **1995-01-09** and latest date **2019-11-20**, the duration between dates is 9082 days.

What I am trying to do is divide the dataframe into **100 time bins,** the number of rows can be different in each bin.

```
movieId time
    21  1995-01-09
    47  1995-01-09
    11  200-01-29
    45  1996-01-29
    18  2019-11-20
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
df['time_group'] = pd.cut(df['time'], bins=100)
```